# Why does the join() now work here?

Tags: java, multithreading, join

i am trying to sum up all numbers from 1 to n with the help of multiple threads.

This is my thread:

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {
//Limits
int lowerLimit;
int upperLimit;
MyInteger result;

//Constructor
public MyThread(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit, MyInteger result){
    this.lowerLimit = lowerLimit;
    this.upperLimit = upperLimit;
    this.result = result;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    //Sums up the numbers in the given interval
    for(int i= lowerLimit; i <= upperLimit;i++){
        result.add(i);
    }
}

}
```

It gets an upper and lower limit and a result which is shared over all threads.

This is my test class:

```
public class Sum {

public static long sumThreads(int numberThreads, int n) {

    Thread[] threads = new Thread[numberThreads];
    MyInteger result = new MyInteger(0);

    // Creates new threads and starts them
    for (int i = 0; i < numberThreads; i++) {
        threads[i] = new Thread(new MyThread(i * n / numberThreads + 1,
                (i + 1) * n / numberThreads, result));
        threads[i].start();
    }

    // Waits for all thread to continue with the return
    for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        try {
            threads[i].join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return result.getValue();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(sumThreads(10, 1000));
}

}
```

If i use only one thread, the result is correct.
If i use multiple threads, the result is sometimes correct and most of the times too low - which means, that the threads did not finish calculating yet. But how is this possible? My for-loop waits for each thread to be finished so the method first returns the result when all thread have calculated their parts.

Best Regards

Edit :

MyInteger class look like this:

public class MyInteger {
    private long value;

```
public MyInteger(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public long getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public void add(int summand){
    value += summand;
}

public void sub(int decr){
    value -= decr;
}

public void increase(){
    value++;
}

public void decrease(){
    value--;
}
}
```

Comment: you should use ExecutorService / Executors..

Comment: What does your `MyInteger` class look like? This looks like a race condition. @Joshua, Executors would only make the underlying issue more difficult to find. There's nothing wrong with simple Threads.

Answer (score 4):

Your `join` code looks correct. I suspect your code is experiencing a `race hazard`:

[Wiki page on Race Condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)

When you have multiple threads running concurrently, all modifying a shared resource, you need to ensure that they have exclusive access while the modification is being performed.

**As a quick fix** to confirm that this is a data race, try adding the `synchronized` modifier to your `add()` method in your `MyInteger` class.

What's ultimately happening is (for a two-Thread example):

1. (Assume `MyInteger` instance has an initial value of 17.)
2. Thread 1 calls `add(3)`
3. JVM (Thread 1) reads/sees that `MyInteger` has value
   of 17, and *maintains this separately during the add operation*
4. Thread 2 calls `add(5)`
5. JVM (Thread 2)  reads/sees that `MyInteger`
   has value of 17, and *maintains this separately during the add
   operation*
6. JVM (Thread 1 *and* Thread 2) increment their respective
   values, so Thread 1 has 20, and Thread 2 has 22.
7. JVM (Thread 1) writes 20 back to the primitive inside MyInteger
8. JVM (Thread 2) writes 22 back to the primitive inside MyInteger

You have now **lost** the result of the `add(3)` operation, as properly atomic operations would have resulted in `25` as a final value.

The most important thing to take away from this, aside from the importance of thread safety, is that *even a simple addition operation* involving primitives is not performed as a single, atomic operation. Rather, it is broken down into smaller steps inside the JVM, which allows for concurrent threads to *race* against each other.

Here is a screenshot of the (excellent) table in the wiki article that demonstrates this visually:

[image]

Comment: Thats it! I didnt think of simple calculations having race conditions. Now i have added synchronized and it works, but: Through this, the whole multiple thread calculation loses its sense, doesnt it? if it allways waits until another thread has added its number to the result. I dont want to use a Callable. Any idea how to optimize it?

Comment: You're exactly right! So your next question should be, "When *does* it make sense to use more than one thread?" And the answer is, when the *activity* takes a long time. Here's a hint: You need to sum the numbers from 1 to 20, and you have two people to do it. You can give them a specific task/input, and they can only come back to you *once* with a result. How can you optimize the way they're working to allow for this?

Comment: How about using an array of MyInteger and each Thread gets its own MyInteger. After join() of all thread, one can build the sum of the MyInteger[] which should work faster and use the advantage of multiple threads. So for your example People1 gets a result for his own and People2 gets one for his own. After both have finished calculating they add up the results which is the whole sum at all.

Comment: That's exactly right. So you'd create a `MyInteger[]` that is the same size as your `Thread[]`, and give each `Thread` its own `MyInteger` with the same index. Then, after your `join()` calls, you (on your main thread, which is the only one left running) loop over the `MyInteger[]` and add up the values. This process is commonly referred to as "MapReduce" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) The "Map" step is giving each `Thread` its own `MyInteger` with a subrange, and the "Reduce" is combining them at the end on the main thread.

Comment: Note that if you're doing this for educational purposes and want to compare performance of one Thread vs. eight Threads, you might find this activity too lightweight to be worthy of multithreading. Computers are *very* good at adding.